# Set specific Google maps API location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to get google maps to show on my website, with a specific pinpoint of a chosen address. In order to achieve this, I am trying to use google maps api, however I can only get the basic view of the map without narrowing it down to my chosen location.

```
         <iframe width="100%" height="400px" 
              frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
              src="http://maps.google.com/maps? hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,
    79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Check this site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you lat lng are 37.0625,-95.677068 you can try

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="0" 
       scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
       src="http://www.google.com/maps/place/37.0625,-95.677068"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try search specific place on maps.google.com, share the location and use embed code.